# how to recover my sent file with get and post

Tags: javascript, php

please I need some help I am really new, so here I managed to send the file by POST method, but now I would like to recover it please how to do?
here is my javascript and php code

```js
var form = document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo");
var oReq;
var oData;
form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {

  var oOutput = document.querySelector("div"),
    oData = new FormData(form);

  oData.append("CustomField", "Données supplémentaires");
  console.log(oData);
  oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  console.log(location.href);
  oReq.open("POST", "stash.php", true);
  oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
    if (oReq.status == 200) {
      oOutput.innerHTML = "Envoyé !";

    } else {
      oOutput.innerHTML = "Erreur " + oReq.status +
        " lors de la tentative d’envoi du fichier.<br \/>";
    }
  };

  oReq.send(oData);
  console.log(oData);
  ev.preventDefault();

}, false);
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/" name="fileinfo">
  <label>Fichier à mettre de côté :</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Mettez le fichier de côté." />
</form>
<div>
</div>
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
    /* Get the name of the uploaded file */
    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    echo $filename;

    /* Choose where to save the uploaded file */
    $location = "upload/".$filename;

    /* Save the uploaded file to the local filesystem */
    if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location) ) {
        echo 'Success';
    } else {
        echo 'Failure';
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is the front-end code. This sends a file to the back-end. Then the back-end should serve the file back to the front-end. But we have no idea what the back-end looks like, what it does with the file, where it stores it, how it serves things.

Comment: @Jérémy it goes to a folder called upload, this is the php code <?php

/* Get the name of the uploaded file */
 $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   echo $filename;
/* Choose where to save the uploaded file */
 $location = "upload/".$filename;

/* Save the uploaded file to the local filesystem */
if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location) ) { 
  echo 'Success';
   
} else { 
  echo 'Failure'; 
}

?>

Comment: OK, that's the code where you store your file on the disk. Good, now how do you access those files? How do you serve static files (images, PDFs, etc) to the browser?

Comment: it is precisely there that I block how to recover the file (it is xml files) of the folder towards my javascript program?

Comment: Ah, well, I guess a quick "How to serve files in PHP" Google search will give you how to do that. I know nothing of PHP, but it's certainly easy; that's whar servers do, serve things.